# I am unable to send putextra with intent, from gridview appwidget to Application

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Hii I am trying to make a widget with a gridview in it. The gridview Items showing thumbnail of movies. When I click on the Grid Item the particular movie should be open in Application.
 But when I click on any Item then intent is fired to open same movie each time. I mean to say  in putextra() Iam sending the movie url but it is sending same url on every click.

code

```
   public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    // position will always range from 0 to getCount() - 
    // We construct a remote views item based on our widget item xml file,
    // and set the
    // text based on the position.       
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_item);

    try {
        rv.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_item, image_url.get(position));
        rv.setTextViewText(R.id.program_id,programId.get(position));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception   
    }
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(StackWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);


    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.widget_item, fillInIntent);


    Intent clickIntent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class); 
    //Bundle bundle.("homeUrl", programId.get(position));
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("homeUrl", programId.get(position));


    clickIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    try{
        clickIntent.putExtra("homeUrl",programId.get(position));
    }
        catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO: handle exception
    }

     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0 ,
    clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
      rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_item, pendingIntent);
       // System.out.println("new ="+bundle);                                                   
    try {
        System.out.println("Loading view " + position);
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Return the remote views object.
    return rv;  
}
```

Provider class;

```
@Override      
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AppWidgetManager mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(TOAST_ACTION)) {
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        int viewIndex = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ITEM, 0);
        String nn=intent.getStringExtra(ETRA_ID);


    }     

}     

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // update each of the widgets with the remote adapter
    for (int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i) {

        // Here we setup the intent which points to the StackViewService
        // which will
        // provide the views for this collection.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        // When intents are compared, the extras are ignored, so we need to
        // embed the extras
        // into the data so that the extras will not be ignored.
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.stack_view, intent);

        // The empty view is displayed when the collection has no items. It
        // should be a sibling                                                                            
        // of the collection view.                                                             
        rv.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view,R.id.empty_view);

    Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidgetProvider.class);
        toastIntent.setAction(StackWidgetProvider.TOAST_ACTION);
        toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetIds[i]);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 0, toastIntent,       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0 ,
    clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); retains only the last clickIntent position, thats why you see the last video

Comment: @Dimentar  So how to set intent?

Comment: Try to rv.setIntent(new Intent()), and rv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener) instead of rv.setOnClickPendingIntent()

Comment: Thanks Dimentar the problem was resolved by using this  clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, programId.get(position));clickIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  // Make the pending intent unique...
  clickIntent.setData(Uri.parse(clickIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0 , clickIntent,0); 
    rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_item, pendingIntent);